# __C_task symbol, what does it mean?

Tags: c, avr, atmega, microprocessors

currently I'm developing a project for an ATMega8 (AVR) microprocessor. I came across the expression:

```
__C_task void my_Function(){

}
```

What does "__C_task" attribute do?

Comment: Well you could just open up your compiler handbook and see what it tells you about this compiler specific flag. That it is compiler specified is indicated by its prefixed "__".

Answer (score 0):

Google says that it's an IAR-specific identifier that tags a function as never returning. The GCC equivalent is the `noreturn` attribute.

```
void my_Function(void) __attribute__((noreturn));

void my_Function(void)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: So, according to that, it'd be valid only for main, right?

Comment: Or for functions you cause to explicitly return via `RET` or `RETI`.

Comment: Ignacio, I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: Which part specifically?

Comment: How can I know if I use those instructions? I'm using C.

Comment: You'll know because you'll have to tell the C compiler that you're writing assembly code instead.

Answer (score 0):

it denotes a "non returning" function (I've seen it being used in ATMEL microprocessor C code where C is a High-level Language :) )

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/porting.html#iar_porting_non_returning_main) site says `__C_task` is equivalent to gcc's `__attribute__((noreturn))`.

In addition, in avr-gcc there are the function attributes [`OS_main` and `OS_task`](http://avr.2057.n7.nabble.com/Add-OS-main-and-OS-task-attributes-in-avr-gcc-4-2-1-td9235.html), respectively. (Both still sparsely documented.)

Apparently, avr-gcc may save "call-saved" registers on the stack even when a function is declared `noreturn`. This may or may not make sense for 'normal' functions, but for (concurrent) *tasks* managed by a task scheduler with context-switching (an "OS") and its own stack mangement on a per-task basis it's just a waste of space on the stack because the task will not return to any caller that requires any call-saved registers to be intact.